# How can I echo changes made in a sed expression to the console?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a simple sed expression:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' blat.xml
```

Because the expression modifies the file in place it is hard to see which lines were changed.

**Is there a way to echo the modified lines to the console?**

Something similar to the output from the following would be ideal:

```
sed -n 's/foo/bar/gp' blat.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

This is specific to GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/gw /dev/stdout' blat.xml
```

You could use `/dev/stderr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but usable without gnu sed. We give up on modifying the file in-place, and assume none of the lines start with "@".

```
sed 's/foo/bar\n@bar/' infile | tee outfile.tmp | grep '^@'
grep -v '^@' outfile.tmp > outfile
```

You can do it all in one step with bash, perhaps with other shells as well:

```
sed 's/foo/bar\n@bar/' infile | tee >(grep -v '^@' >outfile) | grep '^@'
```